# How to execute url using SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I need my SSIS package to just execute or hit an url (which loads a SQL server table). I don't need any parameters to be passed as input other than the url. This is in SQL server 2012. I couldn't find the correct component in in SSIS for this. Please assist.

Web Service task needs a wsdl and since I dont have one, I couldnt use it.

Comment: Opening a webpage requires a UI, which you don't have when a package is running (this is why something as simple as leaving code to display a text box in production code breaks a package). This sounds like an XY problem. If you need to update a table, use a Execute T-SQL task. If you have a web service use that (and download the WSDL, they all have one).

Comment: You could use execute Process Task to call powershell and do an Invoke-WebRequest https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/how-to-execute-a-powershell-script-via-ssis or a c# script task

Comment: Try using [ODATA Source component](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/odata-source?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to hit the URL, use Execute Process task, to run wget or curl commands. These don't come with Windows, buy they are free tools you can download. I think you can also do the same by running PowerShell command, if you don't have wget or curl.